# Finding the associated matrix of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, here's the question that I'm stuck on:

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces with bases $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$. Let $f: V \to W$ be the linear map such that $f(v_i) = w_i$. Find the matrix associated with this map.

---

So, my approach to this starts off with noticing that $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$. They are isomorphic to each other. In fact, the way that $f$ is defined means that it is isomorphic.

Now, consider the canonical basis isomorphism $h_1: F^3 \to V$. That means that $h_1 (e_i) = v_i$. Similarly, there is a canonical basis isomorphism $h_2: F^3 \to W$. That means that $h_2(e_i) = w_i$.

Then:

$f(v_i) = f(h_1 (e_i)) = h_2(e_i)$

Now, given the fact that $f \circ h_1 = h_2 \circ A$, where A is the associated matrix, it stands to reason that $A$ is associated with the identity transformation and so, $A$ is just the 3 x 3 identity matrix.

Is my reasoning above correct? How can I modify it so it's better? This topic has sort of not been covered in the greatest detail in the book I'm using, with no examples given in the text so I'm not quite sure if my approach makes sense or not.

**Edit**
[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

So over here, the author clearly knows that $A$ represents a matrix but he seems to put $f$ and $A$ on the same footing, even making it very clear in the commutative diagram that they’re equal.

My idea for the solution above came from the fact that the commutativity of the diagram just means that:

$f \circ h_1 = h_2 \circ A$

In this case, I’ve just explicitly treated $A$ as the linear map between $F^3$ and $F^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Find **the** matrix associated with this map". If that's literally the assignment given to you, the instructor should be yelled at for a significant amount of time.

You can only talk about **the** matrix of a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ **with respect to chosen bases $\alpha=\{v_1, \dots ,v_n\}$ of $V$ and $\beta=\{w_1,\dots ,w_m\}$ of $W$**. Such a matrix is defined as follows: As $\beta$ is a basis, for each $1\leq j\leq n$, there exists a unique expression of the form $T(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}w_i$. The matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ defined by $A_{ij}=a_{ij}$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I like to denote this matrix by $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$.

Thus in your particular case, $[f]_{\alpha}^{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

**NOTE:** I follow the convention that the linear map assigned to a matrix is given by left action. Thus, if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, it yields a linear map $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n\colon X\mapsto AX$ where $X$ is viewed as a column vector.

Comment: Well, it's more of a multiple-choice thing where it was basically like 'Then, the associated matrix of f is......', then a bunch of options were given. It's basically how the book is structured and I quite like that, actually. But anyways, how did you actually get the matrix? I mean, your answer is the same as mine but is the way I did it correct or no?

Comment: Whether your approach is correct all depends on how you define and interpret $f\circ h_1=h_2\circ A$. What is $A$? A map, a matrix? If it's a matrix, how do you compose is with maps? You are to vague about the definition of a matrix of a linear map to say whether it's correct. That's the point I'm trying to make here.

Comment: Hmm, let me actually take pictures of the two pages in my book where this is discussed and explain what I mean a little more clearly in an edit to the question I've posed.

Comment: The course makes sense. A matrix $A$ is a matrix of a linear map $f\colon V\to W$ if the diagram of the second picute commutes. Note that $\mathbb{F}^n\xrightarrow{A}\mathbb{F}^m$ is the linear map given by $X\mapsto AX$. 

The important bit is that $A$ represents $f$ with respect to the chosen isomorphisms $\mathbb{F}^n\to V$ and $\mathbb{F}^m\to W$. The latter simply corresponds to a choice of bases of $V$ and $W$.

Comment: Yeap that makes sense. So under those considerations, does what I have done make sense? If not, how could I re-word it so it does?

Comment: Yes, what you did is correct. You indeed have that $f\circ h_1=h_2$ thus $A=I_3$ satisfies $h_2^{-1}\circ f\circ h_1=A=I_3$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll certainly have to take note of this entire conversation because I'm still trying to wrap my mind around this. Matrices are just way harder than linear maps :////